# Win ACME DNS validation for Google DNS is not working

Tags: lets-encrypt

I am trying to request a LetsEncrypt certificate using DNS validation. My DNS provider is Google DNS. No matter what I do, I keep receiving the following error:

```
 [EROR] File C:\LetsEncrypt\{GCP-ServiceAccountKey} does not exist
```

Where `{GCP-ServiceAccountKey}` is the Key I generated from the GCP Cloud console.

Below is the command I am running to try and generate the Cert request:

```
.\wacs.exe --target manual --host adfs.public-facing.com --installation script --script ".\Scripts\ImportADFS.ps1" --scriptparameters "'{CertThumbprint}'" --validation gcpdns --serviceaccountkey {Purposely-removed-ServiceAccountKey} --projectid {Purposely-removed-ProjectId} --verbose
```

I'm pulling my hair out here. What am I doing wrong or missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is poorly documented so I had to refer to the source code, but whats expected for the `--serviceaccountkey` parameter is a path to a file where the service account key is stored.